# HiveQL: select values from two columns based on corresponding values in two other columns

Tags: sql, hiveql

Select values from column `A` based on corresponding values in column `Y`, and values from column `B` based on corresponding values in column `Z`. The point is to compare the `aid` and the `bid` values, where each has been selected according to different criteria/columns. An illustrative example below:

I have a table with rows like the following:

```
id   n       aid             bid             prob1
a    3       155321341       155303877       0.03014809320294261
a    4       155303877       155321341       0.05024180995725168
```

I would like to keep the `aid` associated with the highest `n`, and keep the `bid` with the highest `prob1`. In short, I would like something like the following:

```
id   n       aid             bid             prob1
a    4       155303877       155321341       0.05024180995725168
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    id, 
    MAX(n)     OVER (PARTITION BY aid) AS max_n_atthisaid, 
    aid, bid, 
    MAX(prob1) OVER (PARTITION BY bid) AS max_prob1_atthisbid
FROM table.a;
```

But, perhaps for reasons obvious to others, this did not work.

-- UPDATE:
I tried Gordon's code below and it worked great (however, it should be noted that older versions of Hive may not support `DISTINCT` with "window" functions so it may not work for others):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
       FIRST_VALUE(aid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY n DESC) AS max_n_atthisaid, 
       FIRST_VALUE(bid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY prob1 DESC) AS max_prob1_atthisbid
FROM table.a;
```

However, I also want to see the `MAX(n)` and `MAX(prob1)`, so I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
   FIRST_VALUE(aid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY n DESC) AS max_n_atthisaid, 
   MAX(n) AS max_n,
   FIRST_VALUE(bid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY prob1 DESC) AS max_prob1_atthisbid,
   MAX(prob1) AS max_prob1
FROM table.a;
```

But got the following error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 4:7 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'MAX'
```

Is this because I'm not allowed to use `MAX` with a window function, or some other reason I'm unfamiliar with?

Answer (score 0):

Use `first_value()` instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,
       FIRST_VALUE(aid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY n DESC) AS max_n_atthisaid, 
       FIRST_VALUE(bid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY prob1 DESC) AS max_prob1_atthisbid
FROM table.a;
```

EDIT:

You may need to use a subquery:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM (SELECT id,
             FIRST_VALUE(aid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY n DESC) AS max_n_atthisaid, 
             FIRST_VALUE(bid) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY prob1 DESC) AS max_prob1_atthisbid
      FROM table.a
     ) a;
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` in `select` with window functions isn't supported in Hive.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala . . . It is odd that the OP used the construct.

Comment: yeah..the OP must have gotten an error with it for sure.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala I have seen this written elsewhere as well. Perhaps it is now possible due to an update? Gordon's code ran without issue.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I found other claims like Vamsi's, however it ran just fine. My follow-up is, how would I also include `n` and `prob1`? I tried using those two `first_value()` and `MAX(n)`, `MAX(prob1)`, but got an error: `FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line 4:7 Not yet supported place for UDAF 'MAX'`

Comment: i think more recent versions support it..you can also use `count(distinct ...)` and `sum(distinct ...)` in window functions starting version 2.1.0